# simple functions in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

My question is - How do I visualize these two functions [image] ; [image].

For the first one, I've tried -

```
x=-2:0.1:2;
f=@(x)1/1+x.^2
plot(x,f(x))
```

And MATLAB doesnt allow me to place

```
1+x.^2
```

in parentheses. MATLAB tells me - 'Inner matrix dimensions must agree.'. Same issue with second function.

Comment: You don't need "element- wise-power" (the operator .^). Try just to use ^ like `1+x^2`

Comment: @marcoresk Incorrect.  The element-wise operator is required or else for vectors and matrices, `^` would be interpreted as matrix exponentiation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Division needs to be pointwise, too. So you should do

```
x=-2:0.1:2;
f=@(x)1./(1+x.^2)
plot(x,f(x))
```